# Drawline not working with JPanel or JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I cant seem to get the line to appear. I have a Background color and a few pictures. If I have `frame.setSize(x, y);` and `frame.setVisible(true);`
then the outcome is as expected but without the line there. If I change the code and remove `frame.` from these two lines, leaving `setSize(x,y);` and `setVisible(true);`. I have tried using `extends JPanel` and `extends JFrame` but neither work. I have tried adding and removing `@Override`, `paintComponent` and `g2d.drawLine`.

It either one or the other, how do I get both to work?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;


public class CodeBreaker extends JPanel
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Code Breaker!"); 
    Picture picture = new Picture("Empty.png"); 
    JLabel label = new JLabel(picture);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(picture);
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel(picture);
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel(picture);

    JLabel label5 = new JLabel(picture);
    JLabel label6 = new JLabel(picture);
    JLabel label7 = new JLabel(picture);
    JLabel label8 = new JLabel(picture);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    
    public CodeBreaker()
    {

        frame.setSize(600, 900); 
        frame.setContentPane(panel); 
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.setResizable(true); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(141, 100, 21));  

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(label4);
    
        panel2.add(label5);
        panel2.add(label6);
        panel2.add(label7);
        panel2.add(label8);
        
        panel2.setOpaque(false);  
        
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    /*
    void drawLines(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
 
        g2d.drawLine(120, 50, 360, 50);
 
    }
    */

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(120, 50, 360, 50);
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
public class CodeBreakerDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CodeBreaker cb = new CodeBreaker();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a `Picture`? NVM, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: `CodeBreaker` is never added to anything which could paint it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Since the code you posted isn't executable, I went ahead and created the following GUI.

[image]

You can see a black line in the lower right of the GUI.

## Explanation

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Create the `JFrame` and `JPanels` in separate methods.  This makes the code much easier to read and understand.

Use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  I used a `FlowLayout` for both `JPanels`.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the `Picture` class an inner class so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CodeBreakerGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CodeBreakerGUI());
    }
    
    private final Picture picture;
    
    public CodeBreakerGUI() {
        this.picture = new Picture();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Code Breaker!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createBottomPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public JPanel createTopPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 25, 25));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label);
        
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label2);
        
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label3);
        
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label4);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public JPanel createBottomPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 25, 25)) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine(120, 50, 360, 50);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label5);
        
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label6);
        
        JLabel label7 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label7);
        
        JLabel label8 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture.getEmptyImage()));
        panel.add(label8);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class Picture {
        
        private final BufferedImage emptyImage;
        
        public Picture() {
            this.emptyImage = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        }

        public BufferedImage getEmptyImage() {
            return emptyImage;
        }
        
    }

}
```